# Laravel encrypter return error with generated key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I tried to encrypt value using `Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter` but it returns an error.

Error:

```
{ "message": "Unsupported cipher or incorrect key length. Supported ciphers are: aes-128-cbc, aes-256-cbc, aes-128-gcm, aes-256-gcm.", "exception": "RuntimeException",....
```

code:

```
  $encrypter = new Encrypter("evsLYhBx1UAKKervjVIt1aJK0KLHHIf0vETUeI0HaYc=", config('app.cipher'));
  $encryptedValue = $encrypter->encryptString("test value");
```

My app.cipher

```
'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
```

It returns an error that my key is not valid.

I also tried to generate key using this code but it's not working as well.

```
  $key = base64_encode(
    Encrypter::generateKey(config('app.cipher'))
  );
```

I also tried to copy the value of APP_KEY of .env key but not working too.

```
APP_KEY=base64:evsLYhBx1UAKKervjVIt1aJK0KLHHIf0vETUeI0HaYc=
```

How to generate a Key to use by `lluminate\Encryption\Encrypter` ?

Comment: Start by finding out what `app.cipher` is, so we know what cipher and therefore key lengths etc

Comment: @RiggsFolly updated my question, it is  'AES-256-CBC',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
APP_KEY=base64:evsLYhBx1UAKKervjVIt1aJK0KLHHIf0vETUeI0HaYc=
```

The problem is with your key. Your app key is in base64 format so you have to decode when passing it as a parameter of Encrypter.

```
$encrypter = new Encrypter(base64_decode("evsLYhBx1UAKKervjVIt1aJK0KLHHIf0vETUeI0HaYc="), config('app.cipher'));  
$encryptedValue = $encrypter->encryptString("test value");
```